# Room is not frozen yet?

Tags: support, chat, frozen-rooms

The main chatroom for [EOS.IO](https://eosio.stackexchange.com) got deleted automatically (*Which itself is not suppose to happen because it's a mainroon that suppose to have an auto freeze/deletion protection.*), so I created a new room that is  [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83094) with the same name and description as the original main room for a replacement <sub>I creating a replacement instead of contacting a mod to undelete the original one was just me experimenting, just in case you ask why?</sub>

After some days of not having any messages the room is still not frozen yet, **now yes Stack Exchange is posting messages there, but that doesn't count [as said by an official person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238923)** I even saw rooms get frozen even with Stack Exchange posting in them. The last message from a normal user was 35 days ago.

Why is this room I created not frozen yet? Have I managed to fool the system to think that my replacement main room is the real main room?

Also check [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79713/) out it has no  active feeds and it's not a main room.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: No bug here, just sequence of rare corner cases, as far as I can tell.

---

The freeze/delete protection takes place only when there is one single room for a site.

As can be seen in the [list of rooms including frozen/deleted](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=eosio.stackexchange.com), when the main room was deleted in July 28 (2018), [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80778/general) (10k only) existed and was unfrozen and active, thus became the "main" room.

Now why that other room got deleted in August 23? Because [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81152/discussion-between-confused00-and-shawn) existed and was active.

Now... what *that other room* did not get the auto protection? Because it's a "one on one" room, which has different logic behind the scenes, making it "secondary" to the ordinary chat rooms.